# ESLint rule to require one variable declaration statement per line?

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

Is there an eslint (or typescript-eslint) rule to require each var/let/const statement appear on its own line? I've tried `one-var`, `one-var-declaration-per-line`, and `max-statements-per-line`. From my experiments, `max-statements-per-line` is too aggressive, targeting some single-line patterns we commonly use. The other two rules don't correctly catch multiple var statements on one line. Is there another rule or configuration I'm overlooking?

Specific example:

```js
let foo: string; let bar: string;
let blah = function blah() { console.log('woot'); };
```

.eslintrc:

```json
{
  "rules": {
//        "max-statements-per-line": "error",
        "one-var": [ "error", "never" ],
        "one-var-declaration-per-line": [ "error", "always" ]
  }
}
```

No errors reported given this config. Uncommenting the `max-statements-per-line` rule flags both lines. I'd like a ruleset that flags the first line, but allows the second.

Answer (score 0):

The rules you list only apply to *single statements* (i.e. things where it's invalid to put a `;` in the middle). What you have there are *multiple statements* on a single line. It would be similar if you did:

```js
console.log('foo'); console.log('bar');
```

You can prohibit any lines with 2 statements using:

```js
"max-statements-per-line": ["error", { "max": 1 }],
```

---

Tip: There are a ton of these types of issues that are all covered by the `prettier` formatter, and you can integrate it into eslint so that anything it sees as improperly formatted is also a linting error. This issue, all types of spacing/indention issues, wrappable lines, and more all come "for free".

extending `plugin:prettier/recommended` disables a bunch of other rules that would normally conflict, so you can leave out a lot of things from the eslint config like `quotes`, `semi`, `arrow-parens`, etc. because they'll be disabled anyway.

```json
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin",
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    // prettier configs must come last to disable conflicting rules!
    "prettier",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ]
  "rules": {
    // ...
  }
}
```